# How do you do map a property from other properties with custom logic in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

In a manual mapping I am able to do something like the following:

```
//LINQ Query here...
.Select(x => new ViewModel
{
    BooleanProperty = x.OtherProperty > 3
})
```

BooleanProperty would then be true if OtherProperty was 4 or more and would be false if it wasn't. I have been unable to figure out how to do this in AutoMapper. I have tried the following:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.BooleanProperty, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.OtherProperty > 3))

.ForMember(dest => dest.BooleanProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OtherProperty > 3))

.ForMember(dest => dest.BooleanProperty, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<BooleanPropertyResolver>())
```

BooleanPropertyResolver:

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<Address, AddressFormViewModel, bool>
{
    public bool Resolve(Address source, AddressFormViewModel destination, bool member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.OtherProperty > 3;
    }
}
```

For all of these methods when OtherProperty is 4 more more BooleanProperty remains false. How do I replicate the functionality in the manual mapping at the top in AutoMapper?

Comment: Perhaps your configuration is not being applied. Try to make a simple repro.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Other member mappings in the CreateMap function are working fine.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.